# What data int objects contain in Python?

Tags: python, class, object

When I write `a = 1` in python a is a *reference to an object of class int* — Correct me, if I am wrong. So, does the object of class int only contain the *value 1* or it contains other things as well? I searched about this but the answers didn't help me.

Comment: `a` is a __name__ pointing to an `int` object, which happens to have the (internal) value of `1`. The details of this are figured out by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

> When I write `a = 1` in python a is a *reference to an object of class int*

This is correct.

> So, does the object of class int only contain the value 1 or it contains other things as well?

It contains bunch of other stuff also, see:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> isinstance(a, object)
True
>>> a
1
>>> a.real
1
>>> a.imag
0
>>> a.__dir__()
['__repr__', '__hash__', '__getattribute__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__add__', '__radd__', '__sub__', '__rsub__', '__mul__', '__rmul__', '__mod__', '__rmod__', '__divmod__', '__rdivmod__', '__pow__', '__rpow__', '__neg__', '__pos__', '__abs__', '__bool__', '__invert__', '__lshift__', '__rlshift__', '__rshift__', '__rrshift__', '__and__', '__rand__', '__xor__', '__rxor__', '__or__', '__ror__', '__int__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__rfloordiv__', '__truediv__', '__rtruediv__', '__index__', '__new__', 'conjugate', 'bit_length', 'to_bytes', 'from_bytes', 'as_integer_ratio', '__trunc__', '__floor__', '__ceil__', '__round__', '__getnewargs__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', 'real', 'imag', 'numerator', 'denominator', '__doc__', '__str__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__init__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__dir__', '__class__']
```

Comment: A lot of that is class-related stuff accessed *though* the object, rather than being part *of* the object. `a.real`, for example, is to a first approximation the same as `int.real(a)`.

Comment: @chepner Hey, please write a detailed and to the point answer to this question so that I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: @NirajRaut Ask a detailed and to the point question, and you might receive such an answer.

Comment: @NirajRaut So is my answer.

Comment: @ruohola But I didn't say anything to you or about your answer.